Regarding eating meat sacrificed to idols, can hermeneutics reconcile 1 Cor. 8 with Rev. 2?
Revelation 2:14,20 (Yeshua adamantly rejects Paul's stance in what HE says to John?!)

14 But I have a few things against thee, because thou hast there them that hold the doctrine of Balaam, who taught Balac to cast a stumblingblock before the children of Israel, to eat things sacrificed unto idols, and to commit fornication.
20 Notwithstanding I have a few things against thee, because thou sufferest that woman Jezebel, which calleth herself a prophetess, to teach and to seduce my servants to commit fornication, and to eat things sacrificed unto idols.

1 Corinthians 8:8–11 (Paul contradicts Yeshua?! Read also John 10:1-2)

8 But meat commendeth us not to God: for neither, if we eat, are we the better; neither, if we eat not, are we the worse.
9 But take heed lest by any means this "liberty of yours" become a stumblingblock to them that are weak.
10 For if any man see thee which hast knowledge sit at meat in the idol's temple, shall not the conscience of him which is weak be emboldened to eat those things which are offered to idols;
11 And through thy knowledge shall the weak brother perish, for whom Christ died?

Plus, these verses support the legitimacy and inspiration of Saul/Paul by the Holy Spirit:
Acts 13:2,4,9–11 (Luke apparently agrees with Paul and apparently claims THE Holy Spirit does, too?!)

2 As they ministered to the Lord, and fasted, the Holy Ghost said, Separate me Barnabas and Saul for the work whereunto I have called them.
4 So they, being sent forth by the Holy Ghost, departed unto Seleucia; and from thence they sailed to Cyprus.
9 Then Saul, (who also is called Paul,) filled with the Holy Ghost, set his eyes on him,
10 And said, O full of all subtilty and all mischief, thou child of the devil, thou enemy of all righteousness, wilt thou not cease to pervert the right ways of the Lord?
11 And now, behold, the hand of the Lord is upon thee, and thou shalt be blind, not seeing the sun for a season. And immediately there fell on him a mist and a darkness; and he went about seeking some to lead him by the hand.

Acts 16:6

Now when they had gone throughout Phrygia and the region of Galatia, and were forbidden of the Holy Ghost to preach the word in Asia,

Acts 19:6

And when Paul had laid his hands upon them, the Holy Ghost came on them; and they spake with tongues, and prophesied.


What’s the conflict? Eating meat sacrificed to idols AND fornicating or suffering a false prophetess who also seduced others to eat meat sacrificed to idols AND fornicate with Paul saying that merely eating of meat sacrificed to idols is perfectly fine? Paul is not saying fornicate, he also says if your conscience doesn’t allow you it is sin to eat the meat sacrificed to idols. I really don’t see any conflict at all. Maybe be more clear in your question please.

The question lacks clarity and has insufficient detail to support the argument it wishes to put forth. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these principals play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the community of users to maintain the integrity of the site. Welcome to SE-BH.

The point is that, by contradicting Yeshua, should their writings be taken out? You cannot contradict Yeshua and still be biblical. What did Yeshua say and what did Paul say? Any person or group that gets their hand on the bible in an official capacity can add to it(were Paul and Luke added when they shouldn't have been?). Luke seems to me to vouch for Paul in a way that MAY bolster his credibility if Paul was right, but shatter his credibility if Paul was wrong! I set the reasoning forth for feeling that way and you ask why...

They didn’t contradict Yeshua because Yeshua said: ““Hear and understand: it is not what goes into the mouth that defiles a person, but what comes out of the mouth; this defiles a person” (Mat 15:10-11).

Peter admits that there are many things in Paul's writings which are 'hard to be understood'. But Peter did not reject such hard to be understood writings - he called them 'scripture' and 'God-breathed'. This 'question' does not even spend sufficient time explaining what the contradiction is, never mind give a full, substantiated reason for why it is a 'contradiction'. Just quoting a few texts is not a reasonable explanation.

@Marcus says "The point is that, by contradicting Yeshua …" — But the question doesn't make it clear exactly what you think the contraction is. There are 13 verses quoted rather than two simple and obviously contradictory statements.

Okay, Marcus, I revised the title to conform with Biblical Hermeneutics standards and submitted it for reconsideration. Notice that the question now reads as a neutral rather than accusative question. Hermeneutics is most certainly the primary means for resolving this apparent contradiction and I hope your question gets reopened as a result. Welcome and best wishes!

As in all study of the Bible, context is key.
In his description of the church at Pergamum, Jesus describes them as falling into “the teaching of Balaam,” namely the ritualistic and symbolic eating of meat sacrificed to idols and sexual immorality.
Who was Balaam?
Balaam was a gentile prophet who was offered money by King Balaak to curse the Israelites and to sabotage their relationship with God. Then, Jesus continues his criticism of the church at Pergamum with their holding the teaching of the Nicolaitans.
Who were the Nicolaitans?
The name of the sect called Nicolaitans was started by a man named Nicolas of Antioch, who had been appointed a deacon by the apostles in Acts 6:5. However, what he later taught was in direct conflict with the letter that the Apostles and elders in Jerusalem wrote to the Gentile believers in Antioch, Syria, and Cilicia that was delivered by Paul, Barnabas, Judas Barsabbas, and Silas. It’s generally believed that the Council at Jerusalem was held ca. 48-50 AD and the letter delivered soon after. Here’s what they wrote in the letter according to Acts 15:23-29 ESV.

“The brothers, both the apostles and the elders, to the brothers who
are of the Gentiles in Antioch and Syria and Cilicia, greetings. Since
we have heard that some persons have gone out from us and troubled you
with words, unsettling your minds, although we gave them no
instructions, it has seemed good to us, having come to one accord, to
choose men and send them to you with our beloved Barnabas and Paul,
men who have risked their lives for the name of our Lord Jesus Christ.
We have therefore sent Judas and Silas, who themselves will tell you
the same things by word of mouth. For it has seemed good to the Holy
Spirit and to us to lay on you no greater burden than these
requirements: that you abstain from what has been sacrificed to idols,
and from blood, and from what has been strangled, and from sexual
immorality. If you keep yourselves from these, you will do well.
Farewell.”

The following description of the Nicolaitans was written by Ireneus, who was the bishop of Lugdunum, the present city of Lyons, France. The following quote comes from his book, Against Heresies, written very early in church history, about 180 AD.

“The Nicolaitanes are the followers of that Nicolas who was one of the
seven first ordained to the diaconate by the apostles. They lead lives
of unrestrained indulgence. The character of these men is very plainly
pointed out in the Apocalypse of John, [when they are represented] as
teaching that it is a matter of indifference to practise adultery, and
to eat things sacrificed to idols. Wherefore the Word has also spoken
of them thus: But this you have, that you hate the deeds of the
Nicolaitanes, which I also hate.” – Ireneus (ca. 130 - ca. 202 AD),
Against Heresies, Book I, Chapter 26, Doctrines of Cerinthus, the
Ebionites, and Nicolaitanes

In summary from all these sources, the Nicolaitans promoted the following in obvious rejection and rebellion to the letter from the Apostles:
•   Money motivation—as was Balaam
•   Sexual immorality and other sensual desires
•   Idols, rituals, and superstitions being significant
•   Teachings not found in the Bible
•   False views of the Messiah Jesus as our only master and Lord
•   Self-righteous, boastful, manipulative behaviors
Have you ever met or watched such people perform on television?
We find the following descriptions of these people in Jude and 2 Peter.
Excerpts from Jude (commonly dated to about 65 AD)

For certain people have crept in unnoticed who long ago were
designated for this condemnation, ungodly people, who pervert the
grace of our God into sensuality and deny our only Master and Lord,
Jesus Christ . . . Woe to them! For they walked in the way of Cain and
abandoned themselves for the sake of gain to Balaam's error and
perished in Korah's rebellion. These are hidden reefs at your love
feasts, as they feast with you without fear, shepherds feeding
themselves . . . These are grumblers, malcontents, following their own
sinful desires; they are loud-mouthed boasters, showing favoritism to
gain advantage. – Jude 4, 11, 12a, 16 ESV

Excerpts from 2 Peter (commonly dated 65-68 AD)

They are blots and blemishes, reveling in their deceptions, while they
feast with you. They have eyes full of adultery, insatiable for sin.
They entice unsteady souls. They have hearts trained in greed.
Accursed children! Forsaking the right way, they have gone astray.
They have followed the way of Balaam, the son of Beor, who loved gain
from wrongdoing . . . For, speaking loud boasts of folly, they entice
by sensual passions of the flesh those who are barely escaping from
those who live in error. They promise them freedom, but they
themselves are slaves of corruption. For whatever overcomes a person,
to that he is enslaved.  – 2 Peter 2:13b-15, 18, 19 ESV

What did Paul write?

If one of the unbelievers invites you to dinner and you are disposed
to go, eat whatever is set before you without raising any question on
the ground of conscience. But if someone says to you, “This has been
offered in sacrifice,” then do not eat it, for the sake of the one who
informed you, and for the sake of conscience . . . – 1 Corinthians
10:27, 28 ESV

The distinction is that Paul suggested a “don’t ask, but refuse if told” response to being offered meat for dinner and that there’s nothing magical about the meat itself. Paul demonstrates this earlier:

Consider the people of Israel: are not those who eat the sacrifices
participants in the altar? What do I imply then? That food offered
to idols is anything, or that an idol is anything? No, I imply that
what pagans sacrifice they offer to demons and not to God. I do not
want you to be participants with demons. 1 Corinthians 10:18-20 ESV

The difference is that the Nicolaitans promoted idolatry and unrestrained indulgence as a way of life which is clearly not what Paul taught.
Hope this helps.

Would be a better answer if 1 Corinthians 10:19-22 was included. To say there is nothing "magical" about the meat leaves a lot to be desired.

@James, yes, agreed! I had included the quote, but forgot to format it as a quote. It's fixed now.

Nope.
One needs only read 1 Corinthians 10:19–22 to see this is false:

(ESV): What do I imply then? That food offered to idols is anything, or that an idol is anything? No, I imply that what pagans sacrifice they offer to demons and not to God. I do not want you to be participants with demons. You cannot drink the cup of the Lord and the cup of demons. You cannot partake of the table of the Lord and the table of demons. Shall we provoke the Lord to jealousy? Are we stronger than he?

In context, Paul saying an idol is nothing refers to them not being gods compared to the One True God.
With Paul's rationale in 1 Corinthians 8, it's clear he's using another rationale to abandon the practice altogether. 1 Corinthians 10 makes it clear he agrees with Christ.
Chrysostom agrees.

Do you see how terribly Paul rebukes the Corinthians, shaking their very nerves and reducing them to an absurdity? Why, you may ask, did he not say this at the beginning? Because it is Paul’s custom to prove his point by many details, placing the strongest last and prevailing in the argument by proving more than is strictly necessary. Thus he began here with the smaller matters and made his way up toward the greatest of evils, so that the minds of the Corinthians had been prepared by the things already said. In this way the last point is more easily absorbed.


I agree with the OP to the extent that Revelation takes a hard line against eating food offered to idols while Paul sees the rule as unnecessary since the idols have no power. On the other hand Paul also teaches that one should not eat this food if one's Christian brother might be offended or question his own faith because of it.
As to whether any of the OP's quoted scriptures should be removed from the the Bible, I would answer no. But we should be aware than no less an authority than Martin Luther is on record as doubting that the Book of Revelation was inspired scripture:

The apostles do not deal with visions, but prophesy in clear and plain
words, as do Peter and Paul, and Christ in the gospel. For it befits
the apostolic office to speak clearly of Christ and his deeds, without
images and visions. Moreover there is no prophet in the Old Testament,
to say nothing of the New, who deals so exclusively with visions and
images...
Many of the fathers also rejected this book a long time ago; although
St. Jerome, to be sure, refers to it in exalted terms and says that it
is above all praise and that there are as many mysteries in it as
words... Let everyone think of it as his own spirit leads him. My
spirit cannot accommodate itself to this book.

however, Luther's reason has less to do with the issue that the OP raises than with the main text of Revelation - it's apocalyptic visions.
Paul's recognized writings, on the other hand, have no history of being doubted until recently, when scholars began to question the authenticity of some of them, especially the Pastoral Epistles. In any case, the suggestion that their writings be taken out of the Bible must be rejected. The advice that Luther provided is sound: "Let everyone think of it as his own spirit leads him."

"Revelation takes a hard line against eating food offered to idols" — Only two verses, and both of them are not about eating, but about encouraging others to perform the pagan rite: "the doctrine of Balaam, who taught Balac … to eat things sacrificed unto idols" and "to teach … to eat things sacrificed unto idols".
